# Open PDF flex does not work

Tags: apache-flex

Hy,
I use this method to open an PDF file but when I click on the button, nothing happends

```
    private var browser:HTMLLoader;


     protected function onButtonClicked(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            browser = new HTMLLoader();
            browser.width = 100;
            browser.height = 200;
            browser.load(new URLRequest("http://help.adobe.com/fr_FR/flex/mobileapps/developing_mobile_apps_flex.pdf"));`
        }  



            ]]>


        </fx:Script>


        <s:Button x="9" y="67" label="test" click="onButtonClicked(event)" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is a mobile app, you should use `StageWebView`, not `HTMLLoader`. Additionally, loading PDFs will only work on iOS. Android's default browser can't view PDFs prior to 4.3 (and may still not be able to; I haven't tested since 4.4 was released)

If you are on desktop, you **must** have Adobe Reader installed. If you do not, it simply will not work as it uses a Reader window in order to render the PDF.